# When calculating CR, what is the damage per turn for a monster with multiple attacks?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

The online tool https://iadndmn.neocities.org/CRcalc asks for my monster's average damage per turn, but my monsters has multiple attacks.

How do I find the average damage per turn?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take our [tour] if you have a moment. Happy gaming!

Answer (score 11):

### Use the most effective attacks.

The Dungeon Master's Guide answer this in the section on Creating a Monster.

> To determine a monster's overall damage output, take the average damage it deals with each of its attacks in a round and add them together. **If a monster has different attack options, use the monster's most effective attacks to determine its damage output.**

Basically, whatever attack options yields the highest damage is what you should use for CR calculation.

Comment: Might want to mention that this also assumes that all attacks hit.